# Rails 4 + SQL Lite: Find records with substring of big string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do the opposite of this:

`image_name = "blah"`

`Pipe.where("LOWER(name) like ?", "%#{image_name.downcase}%")` (this would find a `Pipe` named 'blahzzz`)

What I want is the opposite, where I have a pipe named `ah` and given image_name = "blah", I want to be able to find that Pipe. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Opposite of that? Do you want `pipes` whose name start with the ending of your `image_name` ?

Comment: yeh exactly so if the image file is `cool_pic-234.jpg` I want the search to find any pipes with `cool_pic` in the name

Comment: I guess that will wouldn't be possible with the traditional `ActiveRecord` queries. Since there are no boundations on how much substring should be chosen etc, there are varying amount and types of queries possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is a functionality of a full-text search index like lucene. search for sunspot or tire, they provide bindings for solr and elasticsearch. those are the most common full-text servers out there.

if you want to find partials of text, there is a feature called n-gram that allows you to find matching parts or substrings. i think that would be the way to go on a larger scale.

if you have just one place, where you are going to implement this functionality and your database is not too large, you can mimic the behavior in a relational database by combining a lot of `OR LIKE` queries and providing substrings of the input.